# wordpress removing index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm not sure what the problem is I followed the steps to remove index.php

1. Added to .htaccess

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. Selected Custom Structure

> http://11.33.55.77/%pagename%/

Any page I visit is a 404 for example

> http://url.com/faq = 404

The requested URL /faq was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the permalink of the faq page is actually /faq, if that's set up properly make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in your apache

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a "page" not a post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled. sudo a2enmod rewrite.
   This did not work for me

instead go to apache2/sites-available/default-000.conf

```
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
```

copy and paste the following configuration